# more functional way of coding this block?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, functional-programming, getjson

I am reading this color value from 3 different links and setting it as background color to some divs. What I am wondering is, if there is a better way to do it, where I won't have to repeat my self. For now its only color values but for the next step I have to read a json file which contains a lot more info. Thank you already!

```
$(function() {
    $.getJSON("url", function(receiveStatusPravdev01){
      var colorBox1 = receiveStatusPravdev01.status;
      $('#box1').css('background', colorBox1);
    });
    $.getJSON("url", function(receiveStatusPravdev02){
      var colorBox2 = receiveStatusPravdev02.status;
      $('#box2').css('background', colorBox2);
    });
    $.getJSON("url", function(receiveStatusPravdev03){
      var colorBox3 = receiveStatusPravdev03.status;
      $('#box3').css('background', colorBox3);
    });
});
```

Comment: "functional" usually refers to [functional programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming). I think you mean you just don't want to repeat yourself. Have you tried anything? Functions are a good way to encapsulate reusable logic, passing in parameters for the bits that vary...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want it functional? Use a `function`!

```
$(function() {
  function loadAndSetColor(url, selector) {
    $.getJSON(url, function(receiveStatusPravdev){
      var colorBox = receiveStatusPravdev.status;
      $(selector).css('background', colorBox);
    });
  }
  loadAndSetColor("url", '#box1');
  loadAndSetColor("url", '#box2');
  loadAndSetColor("url", '#box3');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the redundancy of making the AJAX calls and changing the colors.

```js
function changeColor(el, response) {
  $(el).css('background', response.status);
}
 
[
  {url: "url1", box:"#box1"}, 
  {url: "url2", box:"#box2"}, 
  {url: "url3", box:"#box3"}
].forEach(data => {
  $.getJSON(data.url, function(response) {
    changeColor(data.box, response)
  });
});
```

Comment: OPs code is setting the color of different boxes. Also what's that `changeColor` helper function good for, it's called only in one place?

Comment: @Bergi Oh I missed that, see the updated code.. Also it is a good practice to keep the code modular hence it justifies what I did with `changeColor`.

Comment: Oh sure modularity is good, but you can overdo everything :-) Imo there's no reason to factor a single line out into an extra function if that function isn't reused.

Comment: geez god.. why everyone is so salty here?